# Clipping a raster with a shapefile created with coordinates

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, polygon, pyshp

I created a polygon shapefile this way:

```
def createShapefile(shapefileDir, ROI):
  w = shp.Writer(shapefileDir, shapeType=shp.POLYGON)
  w.field('FIRST_FLD','C','40')
  w.record('poly1')
  ROI = [[float(coord) for coord in pair] for pair in ROI]
  w.poly([ROI])
  w.close()
```

ROI is a list of latitude and longitude coordinates from other raster.
I visualized the shapefile in QGIS, together with the raster image that I want to clip, and it looks good.
[image]

Now, when I am trying to clip the raster using `gdal.Warp`, *None* is returned if I set `cropToCutline=True`, and a damaged (same size as the original file) file if I set `cropToCutline=False`.

```
outBand = gdal.Warp(outputTif, inputTif, cutlineDSName=shapefileHyp, cropToCutline = True)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `outband=None` after to initiate writing operations

Comment: I already had `outBand=None` after `gdal.Wrap`. Do you know any other possible reasons? Could it be related to the creation of the shapefile?